# Is a dual-gate MOSFET different from a two MOSFETs connected source-to-drain?

Tags: mosfet

Is there any other advantage of a dual-gate MOSFET other than combining two single-gate MOSFETs in the common source + cascode configuration in a single package?

Does it have anything to do with reducing the inductance between drain1 and source2? Or maybe to reduce the capacitance from the source1/drain2 connection point?

Comment: Not the same if only because less capacitance when it matters most. https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/fet-field-effect-transistor/dual-gate-mosfet.php Not sure you can do the mixer  with discrete cascode.

Comment: Temperature matching of two die.  Though being in the same package, it'll be pretty good.

Comment: [These answers might help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69300/how-does-a-dual-gate-mosfet-reduce-miller-effect)

Comment: @DKNguyen: I don't see how that article answers that question. As far as I can tell, they never compare the dual-gate to two single-gate MOSFET, but only to one.

Comment: @Aaron: But why would you want the temperature to match in this configuration? The two transistors are in completely different configurations and I fail to see the point of matching.

Comment: @Andyaka: Yes, this speaks for that the capacitance in the connection point is smaller for a dual-gate. Will that give a reduction in bandwidth, though? Will the bandwidth not be dominated by the (larger) capacitance at the output of the cascode either way?

Comment: The capacitance being smaller is trivial. The AC signal voltage at the common point of the two MOSFETs is much lower than for a single MOSFET's drain hence, miller effect is dramatically reduced @nijoakim

Comment: Hmm I guess it never technically says what the difference is other than implying larger bandwidth.

Comment: @DKNguyen and Andyaka: Yes, that is what the cascode configuration does, but that is compared to ONE single-gate MOSFET and not TWO. If you have two single-gate MOSFETs you also mitigate the bandwidth reduction because of the Miller effect, but the question is if somehow the performance becomes even better with a dual-gate MOSFET compared to TWO single-gate MOSFETs.

Comment: My link does not say why but does say that it is better.

Comment: @DKNguyen: In that case we interpret your link differently. I would say it says it says that a dual-gate is better than one single-gate (not two, as state in my original question).

Comment: Isn't that what I said? I did just edit a typo though. You might have better luck finding why a pentode vacuum tube is better than tetrode. They seem to be more well known. There is probably a relationship there.

Comment: Aha, maybe I just misunderstand. I assumed you answered the original question, which speaks about two single-gate MOSFETs. I did not realize you were talking about a single single-gate MOSFET.

Comment: You did not misunderstand. I misunderstood your previous reply. I am answering the original question. I interpreted your question as one dual gate MOSFET vs two MOSFETs in cascode. I interpret the article the same way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136768/discussion-between-nijoakim-and-dknguyen).